# Issue with or operator in Java - ||

Tags: java

I'm writing a password validation program and having some issues with the or statement that checks for special characters. I'm not sure what is wrong with it, the rest of the program seems to function properly, but entering a password that matches the criteria, for example, P@ndas123$%, just results in an infinite loop.

I believe that the problem is related to my big statement for the !pass.contains("") portion. If that is right, could someone help me understand why the statement is incorrect?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DylanJacksonProg5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;
        valid = true;

        do {

            //Password rules declared to user
            System.out.println("Password Verifier");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter a password that meets the following rules: ");
            System.out.println("    Is at least 8 characters long");
            System.out.println("    Contains at least 1 lower letter character");
            System.out.println("    Contains at least 1 upper letter character");
            System.out.println("    Contains at least 1 numeric digit");
            System.out.println("    Contains at least 1 special character of the following set: !@#$%^&*");
            System.out.println("    Does not contain the word 'and' or the word 'the'");


            //Gathering password from user
            System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
            String pass;
            pass = user_input.next();


            //Validating password to rules
            if (pass.length() < 8) {
                int shortlen;
                shortlen = 8 - pass.length();
                System.out.println("Password is too short. Please add " + shortlen + " characters");
                valid = false;

            } else
                System.out.println("Password length is acceptable.");


            //Check for character cases
            boolean hasUppercase = !pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase());
            boolean hasLowercase = !pass.equals(pass.toUpperCase());

            if (!hasUppercase) {
                System.out.println("Must have an uppercase Character");
                valid = false;

            }
            if (!hasLowercase) {
                System.out.println("Must have a lowercase Character");
                valid = false;

            }
            if (hasUppercase) {
                System.out.println("Has an upper case character");
            }
            if (hasLowercase) {
                System.out.println("Has a lowercase Character");
            }


            //Check for digit
            for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
                char x = pass.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isDigit(x)) {
                    valid = false;

                }
            }


            //check for special character
            if (!pass.contains("!") || !pass.contains("@") || !pass.contains("#") || !pass.contains("$") ||
                    !pass.contains("%") || !pass.contains("^") || !pass.contains("&") || !pass.contains("*"))
            {
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("Password requires a special character from the following: !@#$%^&*");
            }

            // check for 'and'
            if (pass.contains("and")) {
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("Cannot contain 'and'");
            }


            //check for 'the'
            if (pass.contains("the")) {
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("Cannot contain 'the'");
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
        while (!valid);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `&&` and not `||`, because you are checking for *not-contains*. In your case the password has to contain *every* special character to be valid.

Comment: Nailed it, Gendarme. It was still looping, so I added a comment to the digit portion. Looks like theres an issue to figure out there, too.

Comment: Every character has to be a digit for `valid` to not be set to `false`. You have to change that. For example, if you find a digit, return without doing anything. Otherwise do `valid = false;`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'd be *very* interested in knowing the rationale behind not allowing `the` to be part of your password. That smacks of causing troubles down the track for perfectly adequate passwords like `thematic!27bX` or `@#!44PanthetiCA`. This is a clbuttic mistake people often make with input sanitisers as well </humour>

Comment: Gendarme, I included a break statement in my for loop, and that seems to have fixed the problem. I tested it a few times with a few passwords, and it seems happy. Thanks again.

Comment: It's a stupid criteria that was part of the assignment. I think it's a terrible idea, too, pax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tell you *one* problem straight up front.

Since you set `valid` to true before the validation loop, and only ever set it to false within the loop, entering an invalid password as your first attempt will result in the loop *never* exiting.

The setting of `valid` to true should be the first thing done *within* the loop.

On top of that, your checks each individually apply to *every* character in the input string, a situation which is impossible. For example, you check whether the entire string is equal to its lowercased variant, then you check whether it's also equal to its uppercased variant.

That means any string with a letter in it will be deemed invalid since `xyZZy` cannot be equal to both `xyzzy` and `XYZZY` at the same time.

It would be more correct to do something like (pseudo-code, and cut down to a few conditions just to show the method):

```
do:
    hasLowercase = false
    hasUpperCase = false
    hasNumeric = false
    isLongEnough = false

    get string from user

    if len(string) >= 8:
        isLongEnough = true

    for each character in string:
        if character is lowercase:
            hasLowerCase = true

        if character is uppercase:
            hasUpperCase = true

        if character is numeric:
            hasNumeric = true

    isValid = hasLowerCase && hasUpperCase && hasNumeric && isLongEnough
until isValid
```

This checks each individual character so that *any* of them (rather than requiring that *all* of them) will mark a condition as true.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution, that what I finally arrived at!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code, which are unrelated to each other:

1. You never set `valid` to `true` in the loop, which means that if you enter 1 wrong password, `valid` will be and always stay `false`, which means that no matter how many *correct* passwords you enter afterwards, the loop will repeat infinitely. In other words: the program will only stop if you enter a correct password at the very first attempt.
2. The big boolean expression is not checking whether the password contains *any* of the characters, it is checking whether the password contains *all* characters. Draw the truth table or apply DeMorgan's Laws, and you will see:

   ```
   !p.c("!") || !p.c("@") || !p.c("#") || !p.c("$") || !p.c("%") || !p.c("^") || !p.c("&") || !p.c("*")
   // is the same per DeMorgan's Laws as 
   !(p.c("!") && p.c("@") && p.c("#") && p.c("$") && p.c("%") && p.c("^") && p.c("&") && p.c("*"))
   ```
3. As soon as you find a single character that is not a digit, you reject the password, IOW *all* characters must be digits.

It should be obvious that #2 and #3 contradict each other, so it it simply impossible to enter a valid password, so even if you fix #1, it will still not be possible to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The OR operators will conflict if you don't have all of the special characters in the password, because in your condition statements, if you have "!" but not "@", it will still result in a false value.

What you can do is check for each special character separately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of explanation, but it is your negation statements in your special character checking block. Usually using !condition works, but it didn't on this online IDE I am using. Not really sure why.

This code will work:

```
//check for special character
if (pass.contains("!") || pass.contains("@") || pass.contains("#") || pass.contains("$") ||
                pass.contains("%") || pass.contains("^") || pass.contains("&") || pass.contains("*"))
{
    valid = true;
    System.out.println("Password requires a special character from the following: !@#$%^&*");
}
else
{
    valid = false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how OR operator works:

```
     if( condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4)
     {
          // .....your code;
     }
```

If condition1 is true,then remaining conditions will not be checked and program will move to inside your IF block.However,if Condition1 is false,then condition2 will be checked.If this is true,then remaining conditions will not be checked,otherwise(if it is false) condition3 will be checked.and so on.However as other peoples have already mentioned there is more problem with your code than just with OR operator.

For example,for password=P@ndas123$%,it does not contain "!",so !pass.contain("!") will give true and valid will be set as false thus causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a 3 issues with your code:

1. valid must be set to true inside your loop before any checks are done on input: 
   `do {
           valid = true;
   ...`
2. lower & upper case checks should be done differently, for example:

   ```
       boolean hasUppercase = false;
       boolean hasLowercase = false;
       for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++){
           if (Character.isUpperCase(pass.charAt(i))){
               hasUppercase = true;
           }
           if (Character.isLowerCase(pass.charAt(i))){
               hasLowercase = true;
           }
       }
   ```
3. your checks for special character are incorrect, you could use below instead:

`if (!(pass.contains("!") || pass.contains("@") || pass.contains("#") || pass.contains("$") || pass.contains("%") || pass.contains("^") || pass.contains("&") || pass.contains("*"))){
    valid = false;
}`

EDIT: actually there's another one: 
4. Your check for digit also won't work, you could use below instead:

```
boolean isDigit = false;
for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) {
    char x = pass.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
        //valid = false;
        isDigit = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!isDigit)
    valid = false;
```